# Remote debugging javascript in IE7

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer-7

Is it possible to attach Visual Studio to a **remote instance of IE7** and debug Javascript? I have enabled script debugging in IE7 and I can attach to the process, but my breakpoints are ignored. Have anyone ever done this?

**Update.** Does not seem possible. Any ideas are welcome though.

Comment: to clarify, by remote do you mean IE7 is on another machine, or in a separatee process to visual studio?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?